# Socket client recv() always returns 0

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, proxy, fork

I'm trying to make a HTTP proxy where, according to the GET/CONNET hostname in the HTTP request, some connections will have higher priorities over others.

The idea is to fulfill requests with higher priority, based on a given list of hostnames, each with a certain priority.

<s>Pending connections will be stored by **accepter** thread in four different queues (one for each class of priority: maximum, medium, minimum and unclassified); **accepter** will then `fork()` a child process, which will dequeue and handle pending connections in order of priority. By doing so, **accepter** thread will always accept new connections and for every enqueued conne
In short, here's my proxy:</s>

- **main**: opens TCP socket, binds to a given port, listens up to 10 connections, calls thread **accepter** passing it the socket fd opened with the previous `socket()` call and joins for this thread;
- **accepter**: this thread gets the socket fd passed from **main** and loops with `accept()` returning client socket, `recv()` from client, parses the request and according to the hostname in the HTTP request a custom struct of mine will be enqueued in the proper queue; it will then `fork()` so a process will dequeue and deal the connection;
- **manageConnection**: this process, forked by **accepter**, dequeues from queues, examines the popped struct resolving the hostname field, opens a socket client, connets to the server and, GET or CONNECT, will fulfill the request.

**New proxy**: no more `fork()`, I made a thread pool of four threads (one "accepter" and three "connecter": since I'm planning to put this proxy on my RPi 2, which has a quadcore processor, I was thinking that at least four threads were good). I now have one `mutex` and two `condition_variables`. The code is almost the same, except for threads, mutexes and condition variables. These are new functions called by threads:

- **enqueue**: this thread contains the `accept()` loop, where it receives from client, parses the HTTP request, finds the hostname and according to its priority, enqueue an `info_conn` struct (typedefed at the beginning of the code);
- **dequeue**: this thread contains the dequeueing and managing connections loop, where it gets an `info_conn` struct from a queue, retrieves client socket (which I got from `accept()` loop), resolves hostname and manage GET or CONNECT request.

**The problem**: always the same, when it comes to manage CONNECT requests, `recv()` from client always return 0: I know recv() returns 0 when the other side of connection has disconnected, but this is not what I wanted!
Based on a thread approach, this is a trivial producer/consumer problem (popping from and pushing to queues) so I think the thread alternation on queueing and dequeueing is correct.

**My (new) code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

#define GET     0
#define CONNECT 1

#define DEFAULTCOLOR        "\033[0m"
#define RED                 "\033[22;31m"
#define YELLOW              "\033[1;33m"
#define GREEN               "\033[0;0;32m"

#define MAX_SIZE            1000
#define CONNECT_200_OK      "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-agent: myproxy\r\n\r\n"

// my custom struct stored in queues
typedef struct info_connection {
    int client_fd;
    string host;
    string payload;
    int request;
} info_conn;

queue<info_conn>q1;
queue<info_conn>q2;
queue<info_conn>q3;
queue<info_conn>q4;
vector<thread> workers;
condition_variable cond_read, cond_write;
mutex mtx;

void enqueue(int sock_client);
void dequeue(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        perror("socket()");
        exit(-1);
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (argc == 2)
        server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    printf("listening to port %d\n", atoi(argv[1]));

    if (bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("binded\n");

    listen(socket_desc, 10);
    printf("listen\n");

    // thread pool, because I suck at forking
    workers.push_back(thread(enqueue, socket_desc));
    workers.push_back(thread(dequeue));
    workers.push_back(thread(dequeue));
    workers.push_back(thread(dequeue));

    for (thread& t : workers) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}

void enqueue(int sock_client) {
    printf("enqueue()\n");
    int client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in *client_struct;
    unsigned int clilen;
    bzero((char*)&client_struct, sizeof(client_struct));
    clilen = sizeof(client_struct);
    char host_name[128];
    char buff[4096];
    int n_recv, n_send;
    char *start_row, *end_row, *tmp_ptr, *tmp_start;
    int req;

    while( (client_sock = accept(sock_client, (struct sockaddr *)&client_struct, &clilen)) ) {
        memset(host_name, 0, sizeof(host_name));
        n_recv = recv(client_sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        if (n_recv < 0) {
            perror("recv()");
            break;
        }

        start_row = end_row = buff;

        while ((end_row = strstr(start_row, "\r\n")) != NULL) {
            int row_len = end_row - start_row;
            if (row_len == 0)
                break;
            if (strncmp(buff, "GET ", 4) == 0) {
                req = GET;
                tmp_start = start_row + 4;
                tmp_ptr = strstr(tmp_start, "//");
                int len = tmp_ptr - tmp_start;
                tmp_start = tmp_start + len + 2;
                tmp_ptr = strchr(tmp_start, '/');
                len = tmp_ptr - tmp_start;
                strncpy(host_name, tmp_start, len);
                break;
            }
            else if (strncmp(buff, "CONNECT ", 8) == 0) {
                req = CONNECT;
                tmp_start = start_row + 8;
                tmp_ptr = strchr(tmp_start, ':');
                int host_len = tmp_ptr - tmp_start;
                strncpy(host_name, tmp_start, host_len);
                break;  
            }
            start_row = end_row + 2;
            /*  if ((start_row - buff) >= strlen(buff))
                    break;*/
        }

        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mtx, defer_lock);
        locker.lock();
        cond_write.wait(locker, [](){
            return (q1.size() < MAX_SIZE || q2.size() < MAX_SIZE || q3.size() < MAX_SIZE || q4.size() < MAX_SIZE);
        });

        cout << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " wants to insert, queues not full " << 
            q1.size() << ' ' << q2.size() << ' ' << q3.size() << ' ' << q4.size() << '\n';
        int priority = 0;
        info_conn info_c;
        info_c.client_fd = client_sock;
        info_c.host = host_name;
        info_c.request = req;
        info_c.payload = string(buff);
        cout << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " looking for " << host_name <<
            " queues" << '\n';
        if (strcmp(host_name, "www.netflix.com") == 0) {
            priority = 1;
            printf("hostname = www.netflix.com, priority %d\n", priority);
            q1.push(info_c);
        }
        else if (strcmp(host_name, "www.youtube.com") == 0) {
            priority = 2;
            printf("hostname = www.youtube.com, priority %d\n", priority);
            q2.push(info_c);
        }
        else if (strcmp(host_name, "www.facebook.com") == 0) {
            priority = 3;
            printf("hostname = www.facebook.com, priority %d\n", priority);
            q3.push(info_c);
        }
        else {
            priority = 4;
            printf("hostname %s not found in queues\n", host_name);                 
            q4.push(info_c);
        }

        cout << GREEN << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " inserted " << 
            q1.size() << ' ' << q2.size() << ' ' << q3.size() << ' ' << q4.size() << DEFAULTCOLOR<< '\n';

        locker.unlock();
        cond_read.notify_all();
    }
    if (client_sock < 0) {
        perror("accept failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void dequeue(void) {
    int fd_client = -1;
    int fd_server = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int what_request;
    char host_name[128];
    char buffer[1500];
    int n_send, n_recv;
    size_t length;
    info_conn req;

    // CONNECT
    int r, max;
    int send_200_OK;
    int read_from_client = 0;
    int read_from_server = 0; 
    int send_to_client = 0;
    int send_to_server = 0;
    struct timeval timeout;
    char buff[8192];
    fd_set fdset;

    printf("dequeue()\n");
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mtx, defer_lock);
        locker.lock();
        cond_read.wait(locker, [](){
            return (q1.size() > 0 || q2.size() > 0 || q3.size() > 0 || q4.size() > 0);
        });

        cout << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " wants to remove, queues not empty " << 
            q1.size() << ' ' << q2.size() << ' ' << q3.size() << ' ' << q4.size() << '\n';
        if (q1.size() > 0) {
            req = q1.front();
            q1.pop();
        }
        else if (q2.size() > 0) {
            req = q2.front();
            q2.pop();
        }
        else if (q3.size() > 0) {
            req = q3.front();
            q3.pop();       
        }
        else if (q4.size() > 0) {
            req = q4.front();
            q4.pop();
        }
        cout << YELLOW <<"(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " removed, " << 
            q1.size() << ' ' << q2.size() << ' ' << q3.size() << ' ' << q4.size() << DEFAULTCOLOR<<'\n';
        locker.unlock();
        // notify one, because I have only one "producer" thread
        cond_write.notify_one();

        fd_client = req.client_fd;
        //memcpy(host_name, req.host.c_str(), strlen(req.host));
        length = req.host.copy(host_name, req.host.size(), 0);
        host_name[length] = '\0';
        what_request = req.request;
        //memcpy(buffer, req.payload, req.payload.size());
        length = req.payload.copy(buffer, req.payload.size(), 0);
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        what_request = req.request;

        //cout << RED <<"(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " copied packet payload " << 
        //  buffer << DEFAULTCOLOR<<'\n';

        struct addrinfo* result;
        struct addrinfo* res;
        int error;
        struct sockaddr_in *resolve;

        fd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (fd_server < 0) {
            perror("socket()");
            exit(-1);
        }

        cout << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " fd_server " << fd_server << '\n';
        error = getaddrinfo(host_name, NULL, NULL, &result);
        if (error != 0) {   
            if (error == EAI_SYSTEM) {
                perror("getaddrinfo");
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "error in getaddrinfo for (%s): %s\n", host_name, gai_strerror(error));
            }   
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (what_request == GET) {
            server.sin_port = htons(80);
        }
        else if (what_request == CONNECT) {
            server.sin_port = htons(443);
        }
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        cout << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " getaddrinfo()" << '\n';
        for (res = result; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next) {
            if (res->ai_family == AF_INET) {
                resolve = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
                //char *ip = inet_ntoa(resolve->sin_addr);
                //printf("%s\n", ip);
                server.sin_addr.s_addr = resolve->sin_addr.s_addr;
                if (connect(fd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
                    fflush(stdout);
                    perror("connect()");
                }
                else {
                    cout << "(DEBUG) thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " connected to " << inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr) << '\n';
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        // dealing with GET
        if (what_request == GET) {
            cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " dealing GET " << host_name << 
                " sending to server " << buffer << '\n'; 
            n_send = send(fd_server, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 0);
            if (n_send < 0) {
                cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " error sending GET request to server" << '\n';
                perror("send()");
                break;
            }
            do {
                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                n_recv = recv(fd_server, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " GET: " << host_name << " read from recv() " << n_recv << " bytes, " << 
                    fd_client << "<->" << fd_server << '\n';
                n_send = send(fd_client, buffer, n_recv, 0);
            } while (n_recv > 0);

            if (n_recv < 0) {
                cout << RED << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " error sending GET response from server to client" << DEFAULTCOLOR<<'\n';
                perror("send()");
                break;
            }
            close(fd_client);
            close(fd_server);
            cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << 
                " done with GET request, quitting\n"; 
        }

        // dealing with CONNECT
        else if (what_request == CONNECT) {
            cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " dealing CONNECT " << host_name << '\n';         
            max = fd_server >= fd_client ? fd_server+1 : fd_client+1;
            send_200_OK = send(fd_client, CONNECT_200_OK, sizeof(CONNECT_200_OK), 0);
            if (send_200_OK < 0) {
                perror("send() 200 OK to client");
                break;
            }
            cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " SENT 200 OK to client " << '\n';

            int tot_recvd;
            int tot_sent;

            // TCP tunnel
            while(true) {
                memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
                FD_ZERO(&fdset);
                FD_SET(fd_client, &fdset);
                FD_SET(fd_server, &fdset);
                timeout.tv_sec = 15;
                timeout.tv_usec = 0;

                r = select(max, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

                if (r < 0) {
                    perror("select()");
                    close(fd_client);
                    close(fd_server);
                    break;
                }

                if (r == 0) { // select timed out
                    printf("tunnel(): select() request timeout 408\n");
                    close(fd_client);
                    close(fd_server);
                    break;
                }

                if (FD_ISSET(fd_client, &fdset)) {
                    tot_recvd = 0;
                    tot_sent = 0;
                    do {
                        read_from_client = recv(fd_client, &(buff[tot_recvd]), sizeof(buff), 0);
                        tot_recvd += read_from_client;
                        cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << 
                            " select(), reading from client " << fd_client << 
                            " " << read_from_client << " bytes, " << fd_client<< " <-> " <<  fd_server<<'\n';
                        if (buff[tot_recvd-1] == '\0') {
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (read_from_client > 0);

                    if (read_from_client < 0) {
                        perror("recv()");
                        close(fd_client);
                        close(fd_server);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (read_from_client == 0) {
                        // this always happens!!!
                    }

                    send_to_server = send(fd_server, buff, read_from_client, 0);
                    if (send_to_server < 0) {
                        perror("send() to client");
                        close(fd_client);
                        close(fd_server);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (FD_ISSET(fd_server, &fdset)) {
                    tot_recvd = 0;
                    tot_sent = 0;
                    do {
                        read_from_server = recv(fd_server, &(buff[tot_recvd]), sizeof(buff), 0);
                        tot_recvd += read_from_server;
                        cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << 
                            " select(), reading from server " << fd_client << 
                            " " << read_from_server << " bytes, " << fd_client<< " <-> " <<  fd_server<<'\n';
                        if (buff[tot_recvd-1] == '\0') {
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (read_from_server > 0);

                    if (read_from_server < 0) {
                        perror("read()");
                        close(fd_client);
                        close(fd_server);
                        break;          
                    }

                    if (read_from_server == 0) {
                        cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " select(), server closed conn" << '\n';
                        close(fd_client);
                        close(fd_server);
                        break;                      
                    }

                    send_to_client = send(fd_client, buff, read_from_server, 0);       
                    if (send_to_client < 0) {
                        perror("send() to client");
                        close(fd_client);
                        close(fd_server);
                        break;
                    }       
                }
            }
            cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " done with CONNECT request\n";
        }
    }
}
```

**Environment**: proxy runs on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04, x86_64; proxy is tested on Chrome with SwitchyOmega plugin, which lets redirect the traffic on a certain port (the same port I will pass to my proxy), compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -o funwithproxyfork funwithproxyfork.cpp -lpthread`.

**Output** (tried for Netflix and YouTube, they both has the same problem, i.e. `client closed conn`, `recv()` returns 0):

```
req: 1, hostname: www.netflix.com, priority: 1
thread 5611 accepting again
(CHILD 5627) is about to handle conn
(CHILD 5627) popped sock_client 4, request 1
req: 1, hostname: www2-ext-s.nflximg.net, priority: 4
thread 5611 accepting again
(CHILD 5628) is about to handle conn
(CHILD 5628) popped sock_client 4, request 1
req: 1, hostname: www2-ext-s.nflximg.net, priority: 4
thread 5611 accepting again
(CHILD 5629) is about to handle conn
(CHILD 5629) popped sock_client 4, request 1
(CHILD 5627) attempting to connect to 54.247.92.196 (www.netflix.com)
(CHILD 5628) attempting to connect to 54.247.125.40 (www.netflix.com)
(CHILD 5629) attempting to connect to 54.247.110.247 (www.netflix.com)
(CHILD 5627) connected to www.netflix.com, dealing CONNECT request
(CHILD 5628) connected to www.netflix.com, dealing CONNECT request
(CHILD 5628) client closed conn
(CHILD 5627) client closed conn
(CHILD 5628) done with CONNECT request
(CHILD 5627) done with CONNECT request
req: 1, hostname: www.netflix.com, priority: 1
thread 5611 accepting again
(CHILD 5630) is about to handle conn
(CHILD 5630) popped sock_client 4, request 1
(CHILD 5630) attempting to connect to 176.34.188.125 (www.netflix.com)
(CHILD 5629) connected to www.netflix.com, dealing CONNECT request
(CHILD 5629) client closed conn
(CHILD 5629) done with CONNECT request
(CHILD 5630) connected to www.netflix.com, dealing CONNECT request
```

Then it says nothing else.

Comment: You do realize you have major design problems with your code, aside from the recv() issue, right? 1. If a client connects, and doesn't send a command but keeps the connection open, your server process will hang, and not accept any new connections until it receives a command 2. fork() clones the entire process space. The child process removing elements from the queue has no effect on the queues in the parent process. Nothing is removed from them. This code will not work even if the recv() issue is fixed.

Comment: I think I got the second point, so I made a thread pool with 4 threads (one looping for accepting connections and three to open and manage connections), since I have a quadcore ARM processor.
Regarding the first point, I did not understand what you meant about the client "sending commands".

Comment: And yet, even with threads and no fork, client still sends 0 bytes to my proxy when handling CONNET request.

Answer (score -1):

From examining the code, this appears to be normal, and due to the way HTTP/1.1 works.

You are probably using some clients that support HTTP/1.1 pipelining. When HTTP/1.1 pipelining is in effect, the server will keep the connection open, in case the client wants to send another request. If the client doesn't, the client closes the connection.

It appears that your code expects the server to close the connection, after responding to the HTTP request, and you do not expect the client to close its side of the connection, first. This is not true with HTTP/1.1, where you can have either the client or the server closing the connection first. Either one closing the connection is normal.

So, there is no issue here, except for several issues that I've noted separately, in the comments, unrelated to the `recv()` issue at hand. Additionally, the code in many places does not sufficiently check the return value from `send()`, and it assumes that all bytes requested have been sent. This is false. You are not guaranteed that `send()` will sent the exact number of bytes requested. It can actually send fewer, and this is indicated in the return value, which is the number of bytes actually sent.

This proxy will start failing when under high traffic load, as fewer bytes will be sent, than was requested, but the code fails to detect this situation, and deal with it correctly. It will, for example, read 2000 bytes from the server, attempt to send them to the client `send()` reports that 1000 bytes were sent, the code continues on its merry way, and the client ends up not receiving the entire response from the server. Hillarity ensues.

Also, there are some other race conditions here that can cause the proxy to get "wedged", or locked up, with HTTP/1.1 clients that fully support pipelining. But if you start having those kinds of problems, this will have to be another question to ask...

Comment: If the client `recv()' returns zero the server *has* closed the connection.

Comment: Nope. If you recv() from a client socket, and you get 0, it is only that socket whose connection was closed.

Comment: You mean I have to send() and recv() checking everytime if all the bytes have been sent or received? Guess I'll wrap this loop in a pretty function.

Comment: Yes, you have to check every time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What do you mean 'nope'? The client got zero from 'recv()` because the server closed the connection. That's what I said and it's also what you said. What are you talking about? I don't know I what 'only that socket whose connection was closed'is supposed to add. Nobody has said anything different. The problem with your answer is that you're talking about the server *not* closing the connection because of HTTP keepalive, whereas the server *has* closed the connection and caused the client to get 0 from `recv()`. There is no 'nope' about it.

Comment: @EJP - in the shown code, the `client_sock` is the proxy's connection to the HTTP client. If its `recv()` returned 0, the client has closed its connection. Perhaps you should review the question. It's about a proxy between an HTTP server and a client, that's handling connections to both. You apparently misread the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If the client has closed the connection it isn't speaking HTTP 1.1. I can't make any sense of what you're saying.

Comment: @EJP - It most certainly speaks HTTP/1.1. It sent a request without a "Connection: close" header, and received an HTTP/1.1 response without a "Connection: close" response. The connection is now persistent, and the server leaves the connection open, after it sent its response. The client decides not to send another request, and closes the connection. See section 14.10 of RFC 2616. This proxy, that the OP is attempting to write, now logs that the client has disconnected.

Comment: He says it *always* returns zero. This is hard to believe unless he is sending an incorrect response. Nothing in the question about 'another request'.

Comment: If the first `recv()` I made on client, i.e. the first GET the clients sent me after establishing the TCP tunnel returns 0, what is the second to last thing I do before looping with `select()`? Sending the 200 OK string to client, done; no race conditions on client and server file descriptors; plus, I read `select()` should be thread safe, as long as different `select()`s in different threads have different `fdset`...I don't know, what could it be?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in your answer you mentioned checking written and read bytes: I started to implement a safe `recv()` as you can see, but it's useless to make the `send()` safe too if `recv()` returns 0 bytes. You said "f a client connects, and doesn't send a command but keeps the connection open, your server process will hang, and not accept any new connections until it receives a command": does this still apply even now with threads implementation?

Comment: Of course your process will still hang. After you `accept()` a new connection, what do you immediately do next? You try to `recv()` the HTTP request from it. If the client never sends the request, your `recv()` will hang forever. The code will wait forever, at that point. Until it `recv()`s the request, the code won't start a new thread, and will not accept any future connections. Using threads, instead of processes, had no effect on this.

Comment: The reason why `recv()` hangs forever is because of its blocking nature...I may made it non-blocking, and check periodically if some data has been received. Will this not stop the process?

Comment: Wait, the `recv()` you are talking about is the one I call right after `accept()` in `enqueue()` function or the other one inside the `select()` loop in `dequeue()` function? Because what gives me troubles is the second one.

Comment: In my last comment, I specifically referred to the `accept()` in `enqueue()`, of course. You asked about "server process will hang, and not accept any new connections until it receives a command". And that's the reason why. As far as the `select()` loop, it has its own problems too, yes. I told you that "sufficiently check the return value from send(), and it assumes that all bytes requested have been sent." Instead of fixing `send()`, you did completely the wrong thing with `recv()`, for some odd reason, and the return value from `send()` is still not checked correctly.

Comment: What's the point of making a checking `send()` in `select()` if earlier I got nothing to send from `recv()`? :(
Is the eventually hanged `accept()` my real problem? The reason why I alwasy got 0 bytes received in `select()` from client ?
This is what I'm not understanding of your reasoning: so far, all the clients sent HTTP requests; is a real case scenario when a client connects to my proxy and then sends to me nothing? 
And how is this related to my always returning 0 `recv()`?

Comment: You [should buy and read this book](http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Sockets-Networking/dp/0131411551) in order to learn more about properly implementing network application that you could possibly learn from a 200 character message on stackoverflow.com